# Disable Forecastfox Weather notification

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, notifications

I use the [Forecastfox Weather](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/forecastfox-weather/) extension for Firefox. It works great. However, I don't want it to notify me after update. If I want to know weather I will look for it myself. Is there any way to disable this notification:

[image: forecastfox notification]

PS: Good solution would be to disable notifications from any Firefox extension because I don't need them at all for any extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to ForecastFox's Options -> Current Conditions

Take the tick out of Enable Alert Slider, do the same for Severe Weather.